# How do I get rid of "." at the end of a token when using solr whitespacetokenizer and worddelimiterfilterfactory

Tags: solr, lucene

I have this text to tokenize :

"let's buy a PowerShot-100 camera."

I am using whitespace tokenizer and then word delimiter factory .

The worddelimiterfilterfactory is creating tokens like "lets", "let's", "buy" , "a" ,"Power" ,"PowerShot", ,"Shot", "100" , "PowerShot100","camera." and also "camera" .

when I try to run a phrase query like this "PowerShot-100 camera." the document's returned but the "PowerShot-100 camera" does not return anything . If I pass a slop of 2 , it returns the document. The start position is same for both tokens "camera." and "camera" . I do not understand why the phrase query "PowerShot-100 camera" does not return anything.

Here's the schema

```html
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="1" generateNumberParts="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />

  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="1" generateNumberParts="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this field type it should solve your problem.

```
<fieldType name="text_delimeter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<!--
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/> 
-->
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: That works. But then the query with "." at the end does not work. Looks like I may need to define a separate field type for phrase queries. Thank you.